# Looping through and displaying multiple table rows from database sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im trying to loop through my database and displaying every row. I don't know what is wrong with my code but it is not displaying anything at all... Can anyone help?

```
<?php

$players = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($players)) {
    $steamid = $row["name"];
    $profilename = $row["profilename"];
    $profileurl = $row["profileurl"];
    $avatar = $row["avatar"];
    $region = $row["region"];


?>


<p><?php echo $name ?></p>
<p>><?php echo $profilename ?></p>
<p>><?php echo $profileurl ?></p>
<p><?php echo $avatar ?></p>


<?php
}
?>
```

This is where im including this file:

```
<?php include 'fetch_players.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Do you get a 500? Are you running PHP 7? `$name` is not defined but that should only throw a warning (incorrect assigning here possibly `$steamid = $row["name"];`). Do you have a database connection?

Comment: stop using deprecated  `mysql_*` use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: you're just assuming the query succeeded. bad assumption. never EVER assume success. `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())` should be the absolute barebones/minimum acceptable error handling. and even then, you shouldn't be using the mysql_*() functions anymore. they're dead/gone and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Thank you both for ur answers. Have updated it and Anant u were correct! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of using `mysqli_*` with correct approach is given below. Please take care of comments too:-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); // check all type of error
ini_set('display_errors',1); // display those error
$connection = mysqli_connect('hostname','username','password','dbname'); // provide your db credentials here
$final_data = array(); // create empty array
if($connection){
    $players = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM users");
    if($players){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($players)) {
            $final_data[$row['id']]['name'] = $row['name']; // assign values id wise to the array
            $final_data[$row['id']]['profilename'] = $row['profilename'];
            $final_data[$row['id']]['profileurl'] = $row['profileurl'];
            $final_data[$row['id']]['avatar'] = $row['avatar'];
            $final_data[$row['id']]['region'] = $row['region'];
        }
    }else{
        echo "query execution failed because of". mysqli_error($connection);
    }
}else{
  echo "db connection error because of". mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>

<?php 
if(count($final_data) >0){ // check array have some value or not?
foreach($final_data as $final_dat){?>
    <p><?php echo $final_dat['name'] ?></p><!-- print out values -->
    <p><?php echo $final_dat['profilename'] ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $final_dat['profileurl'] ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $final_dat['avatar'] ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $final_dat['region'] ?></p>
<?php }}?>
```

Comment: This fixed my issue. Thank you @Anant :)

Comment: What do you mean with this tho: // assign values id wise to the array

Comment: means create array index based on row id's which is always unique, so no over-write will happen in any case and you will get all data